# Removing default data of a text box while clicking the text

Tags: javascript

As you know I want to remove default value of a text box while clicking on it, This code works.
But when I click on the box and then click again another part of screen (I mean out of textbox) the data won't come back.
what should I do?

```
  <html><head><title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function make_blank()
  {
  document.form1.type.value ="";
  }
  </script>

  </head>
  <body >

  <form name=form1 method=post action='test.php'>
  <input type=text name=type value='Enter your user id' onclick="make_blank();">Enter User ID
     <b>Type</b>
  <input type=submit value=Submit> </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That isn't a default value. It is a label. It should be in a `<label>` element, not a value attribute. Don't create accessibility problems by abusing the value attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is one of the following, depending on whether you're using HTML5 or XHTML (or HTML4). Since you're not stating which one you're using, I'll add both.

By the way, you really want to use the focus event, and not the click event. This is because a user can also navigate to a form field using his/her keyboard or by other access keys.

As Quentin correctly [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263479/removing-default-data-of-a-text-box-while-clicking-the-text/12263782#comment16442906_12263782), [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) is clear about what a placeholder text is supposed to be used for. Therefore I've updated the text you're using to something more fitting.

**HTML5**

```
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder="email@example.com">
```

**XHTML**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="type" value="email@example.com"
    onfocus="make_blank(this);"  onblur="restore_placeholder(this);" />
```

Javascript:

```
function make_blank (oInput)
{
    if (!('placeholder' in oInput))
        oInput.placeholder = oInput.value;
    if (oInput.value != oInput.placeholder)
        oInput.value = '';
}

function restore_placeholder (oInput)
{
    if (oInput.value == '' && 'placeholder' in oInput)
        oInput.value = oInput.placeHolder;
}
```

Comment: Note [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute). *The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format.* and *The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.*

Comment: @Quentin True. I've updated the example. Also fixed it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following combination of HTML5 and JavaScript (for HTML4) works nice for me:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder="email@example.com" 
       onfocus="make_blank(this);"
       onblur="restore_placeholder(this);" />
```

Javascript:

```
function make_blank(oInput) {
    if (oInput.value == 'placeholder') {
        oInput.value = '';
    }
}

function restore_placeholder(oInput) {
    if (oInput.value == '') {
        oInput.value = 'placeholder';
    }
}
```